# error getting while database create in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i m install a bundle after for create database run this commond in terminal

```
rake db:migrate
```

then this error appears.Please help me what is the problem

```
dominname@dominname204:~/Desktop/ajaxtree$ rake db:create

NOTE: Gem.cache is deprecated, use Gem::source_index. It will be removed on or after 2011-08-01.

Gem.cache called from /home/domainname/Desktop/ajaxtree/config/boot.rb:25.

NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.

Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1144.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#search is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.

Gem::SourceIndex#search called from /home/domainname/Desktop/ajaxtree/config/boot.rb:25.

/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:Warning: Gem::SourceIndex#search support for String patterns is deprecated, use #find_name
Cannot find gem for Rails =1.1.4:

    Install the missing gem with 'gem install -v=1.1.4 rails', or
    change environment.rb to define RAILS_GEM_VERSION with your desired version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the new version of ruby in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 1.1.4 is very very old. But, with the right gemset you might have a go.

Try what the error message is telling you:

```
gem install -v=1.1.14 rails
```

If you have all the gem versions in the environment.rb, you stand a chance at being able to install your dependencies.